# why I get different results

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Why I get different results when I use method update of group sprite objects during drawing to the screen. When thru calling method I get only one row of sprites and when I run for loop and move y axis of every sprite by one I get the whole swarm (several rows) moving down.
Here is the code

drop.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Drop(Sprite):
"""Class that represent single drop in rain"""

    def __init__(self, settings, screen):
        """Initialize drop and sets its starting position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings

        #Load drop image and sets its rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/drop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Start each drop on top-left on the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #store drop exact position
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)


    def update(self):
        self.y += 1
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

I have all functions stored in separate file. Just to keep it less cluttered. Where in function update_screen() is in comments described in code the problem I do not understand why makes difference looping thru sprites and that way changing y axis and getting whole group of them moving, but when I use method of sprite object .update() they are in group I get only partial group moving on screen.

func_rain.py

```
import pygame
import sys
from drop import Drop
from time import sleep

def create_rain(settings, screen, drops):
    """Create a fleet of drops."""
    #Create an drop and find the number of drops in a row and number rows

    drop = Drop(settings, screen)
    number_drops_x = get_number_drops_x(settings, drop.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(settings, drop.rect.height)

    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for drop_number in range (number_drops_x):
            create_drop(settings, screen, drops, drop_number, row_number)      

def get_number_drops_x(settings, drop_width):    
    """Determine the number of drops that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = settings.screen_width - 2 * drop_width
    number_drops_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * drop_width))
    return number_drops_x


def get_number_rows(settings, drop_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of drops that fit on the screen."""
    available_space_y = (settings.screen_height -  drop_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * drop_height))
    return number_rows


def create_drop(settings, screen, drops, drop_number, row_number):
    """Create drop and place it in the row"""

    drop = Drop(settings, screen)
    drop_width = drop.rect.width
    drop.x = drop_width + 2 * drop_width * drop_number
    drop.rect.x = drop.x
    drop.rect.y = drop.rect.height + 2 * drop.rect.height * row_number
    drops.add(drop)


def check_keydown_events(event):
    """Respond to key presses"""                     
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()


def check_events():
    """Respond to keypress and mouse events"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event)


def update_screen(settings, screen, drops):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(settings.bg_color)
#This loop
    for drop in drops:
        drop.rect.y += 1
"""Here is the problem!!!!!! if I use for loop just above I get whole group      
   consisting from 5 rows of drops (image has resolution 50*62 pix). But when 
   I use drops.update() commented below (no for loop) I get on screen only
   one row of drops."""
    #drops.update()
    drops.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

rain_settings.py

```
 class Settings():
    """A class to store all ran settings"""

    def __init__(self):
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (100, 100, 100)
```

And last main file.
rain.py

```
import pygame
from rain_settings import Settings
import func_rain as fr
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run_rain():
    """Initialize pygame and screen object"""
    pygame.init()
    settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (settings.screen_width, settings.screen_height))

    drops = Group()
    fr.create_rain(settings, screen, drops)

    while True:

        fr.check_events()
        fr.update_screen(settings, screen, drops)    


run_rain()
```

I would really appreciate If someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong. I can't figure it out. please

Comment: But when I use in update() class method for x-axis I can see all sprites in several rows moving to the right as it supposed to be. I placed also print statement in both cases in to main loop and in both cases there are 54 sprites created and changing them position in either direction. So my trouble persist. I still cannot figure out why only y-axis is causing me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been playing around and I get the movement of sprites thru class method update to work.

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.y += 1
```

Altho it still remains to me a mystery why directly changing the **self.rect.y** works and indirect change on y attribute don't.